# Magnetometer perpendicular to ground plane

Tags: sensor, magnetometer

A team and I are building some wearable tech that needs a magnetometer to know your heading. Unfortunately, we have to mount it "vertically" - imagine that the board is flat against your stomach/waist.

As all magnetometers that I know of require you to be parallel to the ground, I'm wondering if anybody knows of any sensor boards in which the internal circuitry is rotated 90° such that it allows you to be *perpendicular* to the ground plane or any other methods which we can use that allows us to determine our heading with a board that's vertical/perpendicular to the ground.

Note: the sensor will be interfacing with an Arduino.

Thanks!

Comment: There are plenty of 3-D magnetometers; just get one of those and select the two axes that you need.

Comment: Why would you try to mount an IC vertically on a wearable..?